# Sort Content using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, sorting

I have Home Team and away Team Scorer in my HTML and i want to sort each Goal Scorer in Minutes (Ascending). Here is the HTML Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sort</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  (function(angular) {
  'use strict';
    angular.module('orderByScore', [])
    .controller('ScoreController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.goals =
        [{scorer:'Glen', mins:'40"', type:'Own Goal', min:40},
         {scorer:'Beckham', mins:'20"', type:'Goal', min:20},
         {scorer:'Ronaldo', mins:'70"', type:'Own Goal', min:70}];

  }]);

    })(window.angular);
  </script> 
    <script>
  (function(angular) {
  'use strict';

    angular.module('orderByScore', [])
    .controller('ScoreControllerX', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.goalsx =
        [{scorer:'Glen', mins:'4"', type:'Goal', min:4},
         {scorer:'Glen', mins:'75"', type:'Goal', min:75},
         {scorer:'David', mins:'30"', type:'Own Goal', min:30}];

  }]);

    })(window.angular);
  </script> 





</head>
<body ng-app="orderByScore">
  <div ng-controller="ScoreController">
  <div class="home-team col-md-6">
    <table class="goalx">
        <tr style="display: none">
          <th>Scorer</th>
          <th>Minute</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Min</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="goalx in goalsx | orderBy:'+min'">
          <td>{{goal.scorer}}</td>
          <td>{{goal.mins}}</td>
          <td>{{goal.type}}</td>
          <td style="display: none">{{goal.min}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>  
    <div class="away-team col-md-6">
        <table class="goal">
        <tr style="display: none">
          <th>Scorer</th>
          <th>Minute</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Min</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="goal in goals | orderBy:'+min'">
          <td>{{goal.scorer}}</td>
          <td>{{goal.mins}}</td>
          <td>{{goal.type}}</td>
          <td style="display: none">{{goal.min}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

If away team is working, home team is not displaying. if home team display the away team is dissappear. I want the home and away team scorer display. Please Help to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

replace goal with goalx in ng-repeat="goalx in goalsx | orderBy:'+min' like  {{goalx.scorer}}

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `ng-repeat` with filters. In your case, you will have to use `orderby` filter.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="goal in goalsx | orderBy:'goal.mins'">{{goal.scorer}}</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In home team's case you used "ng-repeat = goalx in goalsx" but inside the div everywhere you used "goal.scorer","goal.miins", etc. All you have to do is replace the ng-repeat as "ng-repeat = goal in goalsx".

```
<div class="home-team col-md-6">
    <table class="goalx">
        <tr style="display: none">
          <th>Scorer</th>
          <th>Minute</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Min</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="goal in goalsx | orderBy:'+min'"> // use 'goal in goalsx' here
          <td>{{goal.scorer}}</td>
          <td>{{goal.mins}}</td>
          <td>{{goal.type}}</td>
          <td style="display: none">{{goal.min}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>  
<div class="away-team col-md-6">
    <table class="goal">
        <tr style="display: none">
          <th>Scorer</th>
          <th>Minute</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Min</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="goal in goals | orderBy:'+min'">
          <td>{{goal.scorer}}</td>
          <td>{{goal.mins}}</td>
          <td>{{goal.type}}</td>
          <td style="display: none">{{goal.min}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```